# Measure the "matching"?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Is there mechanism to measure or compare of how tight the pattern  corresponds to the given string? By pattern I mean regex or something similar. For example we have string **"foobar"** and two regexes: **"fooba."** and **".*"** Both patterns match the string.  Is it possible to determine that "fooba." is more appropriate pattern for given string then ".*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are metrics and heuristics for string 'distance'. Check this for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Here is one random Java implementation that came with Google search.

http://www.merriampark.com/ldjava.htm

Some metrics are expensive to compute so look around and find one that fits your needs.

As for your specific example, IIRC, regex matching in Java prioritizes terms by matching length and then order so if you use something like

"(foobar)|(.*)", it will match the first one and you can determine this by examining the results returned for the two capture groups.

Comment: Need more coffee to understand, but seems to be the most promissing way to deeg. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for an idea: Use the length of your regular expression:  `length("fooba.") > length(".*")`, so `"fooba."` is more specific...

However, it depends on where the regular expressions come from and how precise you need to be as `"fo.*|.*ba"` would be longer than `"fooba."`, so the solution will not always work.

Comment: Unfortunately, patterns like "foob", "foo.", "fo*." usually come together. Anyway, thank your for the simple first aproarch.

Comment: I suppose you could always remove any non-alpha characters from the regexp before comparing the length.

Comment: ...Or to make some heuristics for weighting special characters. That may work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't really a property of regular expressions.

Create an enum that measures "closeness", and create a class that will hold a given regex, and a closeness value. This requires you to determine which regex is considered "more close" than another.

Instantiate your various classes, and let them loose on your code, and compare the matched objects, letting the "most closeness" one rise to the top.

pseudo-code, without actually comparing anything, or resembling any sane language:

```
enum Closeness
  Exact
  PrettyClose
  Decent
  NotSoClose
  WayOff
  CouldBeAnything
mune

class RegexCloser
  property Closeness Close()
  property String Regex()
ssalc


var foo = new RegexCloser(Closeness := Exact, Regex := "foobar")
var bar = new RegexCloser(Closeness := CouldBeAnything, Regex := ".*")

var target = "foobar";

if  Regex.Match(target, foo)
  print String.Format("foo {0}", foo.Closeness)
fi

if Regex.Match(target, bar)
  print String.Format("bar {0}", bar.Closeness)
fi
```

Comment: At my domain, all patterns are made by end user. As I can understand, that means that with this aproarch the end-user need to explicitly weight every pattern. I doubt it will be suitable.